# Implementing Priority Queue

Tags: c++, queue, priority-queue, traversal

I am attempting to implement insertion, find minimum, and delete minimum functions for a primary queue. I also have tests to ensure that my code is working properly by checking it alongside another queue. For some reason, when utilizing the find minimum and delete minimum functions, it is coming with different values from the other queue. How can I fix this?

```
#include "pQueue.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace tom;

status pQueue::insert(int insertInt)
{

    if (q[0] == NULL)
    {
        q[0] = insertInt;
        minimum = insertInt;
    }
    else if (q[0] != NULL)
    {
        q[count] = insertInt;
    }
    else
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if (insertInt < minimum)
    {
        minimum = insertInt;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
    count++;

}

status pQueue::findMin(int &minElement)
{

    minElement = minimum;

    if (minElement == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

status pQueue::deleteMin()
{

    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
    {
        if (q[i] = minimum)
        {
            q[i] = 0;
        }
        if (q[i] != 0)
        {
            return FAILURE;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code, the most glaring of which is that `count` is never incremented because you return before it can be. That should give you a compiler warning. You should at least understand (preferably eliminate) all compiler warnings before you try to test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea for an unsorted priority queue is, assuming you're storing it in an array, is:

Insertion:

1. Add item as the last item in the array.
2. Increment `count`.

Removal:

1. Scan the array to find the index of the smallest item.
2. Copy the value from that index to a variable called `result`
3. Copy the last value in the array to that location
4. Decrement `count`.
5. Return `result`

So insert becomes (in pseudo-code)

```
insert(value)
    a[count] = value
    count = count + 1
```

deleteMin is:

```
deleteMin()
    minIndex = findMinIndex()
    result = a[minIndex]
    a[minIndex] = a[count-1]
    count = count - 1
    return result
```

findMinIndex is:

```
findMinIndex()
    if (count < 1) then error
    minIndex = 0
    for (i = 1; i < count; ++i)
        if (a[i] < a[minIndex])
            minIndex = i
    return minIndex
```

And findMin is:

```
findMinIndex()
    return a[findMinIndex()]
```

I'll leave the C++ implementation to you.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What do you think this code is doing? `if (q[0] == NULL)` is equivalent to `if (q[0] == 0)`. Are the values you are inserting never 0? Also, no matter what, your first function will never return FAILURE. The code you have written does not implement priority queue functionality at all. Read CLRS(https://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844) and implement this in a easier language (like Python) first.

Comment: how would I go about checking whether an array's position has been filled?

Comment: also, if it changes anything, this is supposed to be for an unsorted priority queue, and I must do it in c++